# new decade: how to utter something like `find /path/ -name 'file.20{19,20}*'` (but which works)

Tags: find, wildcards, gnu

**summary:**

1. A given system has lots text files with names `~=` `[type of file].[8-digit date]`.
2. To search these files, I like (and wanna keep) using this idiom: `find /path/ -name 'file.nnnn*' -print | xargs -e fgrep -nH -e 'text I seek'` (where `nnnn` == 4-digit year)
3. ... and in the past decade I also made `find` glob across years like `find /path/ -name 'file.201[89]*' -print | xargs ...`
4. ... but now I can't make `find` glob across 2019 and 2020 with `find /path/ -name 'file.20{19,20}*' -print | xargs ...`
5. ... although that "curly-brace globbing" (correct term?) works fine with `ls`!

Is there a {concise, elegant} way to tell `find` what I want, without instead doing post-`find` cleanup (i.e., what I'm doing now) à la

```
find /path/ -name 'file.*' -print | grep -e '\.2019\|\.2020' | xargs ...
```

? FWIW, I'd prefer a solution that works with `xargs`.

**details:**

I work on a system with lotsa conventions which long precede me and which I cannot change. One of those is, it has lotsa text files with names `~=` `[type of file].[8-digit date]`, e.g., `woohoo_log.20191230`. When searching within these files for some given text, I typically (as in, almost always) use the `find ... grep` idiom (often using Emacs' `M-x find-grep`). (FWIW, this is a Linux system with

```
$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2
...
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

and I currently lack status to change either of those, if I wanted to.) I often kinda know the year range of the matter-at-hand, and so will try to constrain what `find` returns (to speed processing), with (e.g.)

```
find /path/ -type f -name 'file.nnnn*' -print | xargs -e fgrep -nH -e 'text I seek'
```

where `nnnn` == 4-digit year. This WFM, and I like (and wanna keep) using the above idiom ... especially since I can also use it to search across years like

```
find /path/ -type f -name 'file.201[89]*' -print | xargs ...
```

But this new decade seems to be breaking that idiom, and (to me at least) most oddly. (I wasn't here when the last decade changed.) Suppose I choose text that I **know** is in a file from 2019 && a file from 2020 (as in, I can open the files and see the text). If I currently do

```
find /path/ -name 'file.20{19,20}*' -print | xargs ...
```

`grep` unexpectedly/annoyingly finishes `with no matches found`, because

```
$ find /path/ -name 'file.20{19,20}*' -print | wc -l
0
```

But if I do

```
find /path/ -type f -name 'file.*' -print | grep -e '\.2019\|\.2020' | xargs ...
```

`grep` returns the expected results. Which is nice, but ... ummm ... that's just ugly, esp since this "curly-brace glob" (please correct me if this usage is incorrect or otherwise deprecated) works from `ls`! I.e., this shows me the files in the relevant year range (i.e., 2019..2020)

```
ls -al /path/file.20{19,20}*
```

Hence I'd like to know:

1. Am I just not giving `find` the right glob for this usecase? What do I need to tell `find` to make it do what `ls` is capably/correctly doing?
2. Is this a problem with `xargs`? If so, I can live with a `find ... -exec` solution, but ... my brain works better with `xargs`, so I'd prefer to stay with that if possible. (Call me feebleminded, but `-exec`'s syntax [makes my brain hurt](https://montypython.fandom.com/wiki/Gumbys).)

Comment: No nice way, sorry. You may try `eval find /path '\(' -name no-such-name-ever '-o -name file.20'{19,20}* '\)'`. Or simpler, with GNU find: `eval find /path '\(' -false '-o -name file.20'{19,20}* '\)'`. You better use a function which creates the command line.

Comment: If you don't have any decade-old (or future-dated) files, you could use `find /path/ -name 'file.20[12][09]*' ...` -- that'll match 2010, 2019, 2020, and 2029.

Comment: I appreciate that you added enough informations about the context as well. Your `-name 'file.20{19,20}*'` isn't expanded because it is inside single quotes. But if it was, it wouldn't do what you want either as it would expand to  something along: `-name file.2019* file.2020*` or `-name "file.2019* file.2020*"`, which would be incorrect. See Stephane Chazelas's correct posix answer : ` \( -name 'file.2019*' -o -name 'file.2020*' \)` is what you'd need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `zsh`, you could use recursive globbing and its `<x-y>` glob operator which matches on ranges of decimal numbers:

```
grep -nHFe 'text I seek' /path/**/file.<2019-2020>*(D-.)
```

(the `(D)` to also look into hidden (`D`ot) dirs as `find` would; presumably you can omit it if you don't want them, and `-.` is to restrict to *regular* file (`.`) identified after symlink resolution (`-`)).

Note that it would also match on `file.00002020` (as that's a decimal number between 2019 and 2020) and like in your approach on `file.20201234` as its `file.2020` which matches `file.<2019-2020>` followed by `1234` which matches `*`.

The standard (POSIX `sh` and utilities) way to do it would be with:

```
find /path \( -name 'file.2019*' -o -name 'file.2020*' \) -type f \
  -exec grep -Fne 'text I seek' /dev/null {} +
```

(where adding `/dev/null` gets you the same effect as GNU `grep`'s `-H` to force the file name to be displayed)

Note that the output of `find -print` is not compatible with the expected input format of `xargs`. With GNU utilities, you can use `find -print0` and `xargs -r0`, but that's not needed as `find -exec ... {} +` has the same behaviour, is shorter and more portable.

Comment: `<quote>standard (POSIX sh and utilities) way to do it</quote>` ... works with `xargs` and Emacs `M-x find-grep`, thanks. <linebreak/> `<quote>Note that the output of find -print is not compatible with the expected input format of xargs.</quote>` Not sure what you mean by 'compatible.' Empirically, I've been doing `find ... -print | xargs ...` for literally decades, in scripts, at commandline, and via Emacs.

Comment: @TomRoche see for instance [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 6):

In `ls -al /path/file.20{19,20}*`, it's not `ls` that does anything with `{19,20}*`. In that command, the shell performs [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) and [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) on `/path/file.20{19,20}*` as **it is not quoted**:

```
bash-5.0$ set -x
bash-5.0$ echo {a,b}
+ echo a b
a b
bash-5.0$ ls {a,b}
+ ls a b
ls: cannot access 'a': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'b': No such file or directory
bash-5.0$ find -iname {a,b}
+ find -iname a b
find: paths must precede expression: `b'
```

In `find /path/ -name 'file.20{19,20}*'`, `'file.20{19,20}*'` is quoted, so the shell leaves it alone, and `find` then applies its own [pattern matching rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Shell-Pattern-Matching), which do not support brace expansion. Here quoting the [GNU `find` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Base-Name-Patterns):

> Braces within the pattern (‘`{}`’) are not considered to be special
>   (that is, `find . -name 'foo{1,2}'` matches a file named `foo{1,2}`,
>   not the files `foo1` and `foo2`.

If you really want to use brace expansion to recursively search a directory, in bash, you can enable recursive globbing ([`globstar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)) (and possibly `dotglob` to look into hidden directory like `find` would), and use `printf` with `xargs`:

```
shopt -s globstar
printf "%s\0" /path/**/file.20{19,20}* | xargs -0 ...
```

Or you can use `find` with `-regex` instead of `-name` as supported by a few `find` implementations. With GNU `find`:

```
find  /path -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/file.20(19|20)[^/]*'
```

Comment: `\( -name 'file.2019*' -o -name 'file.2020*' \)` would be shorter to type, and harder to get wrong (arguably), and more portable.

Comment: Or `-regex .*/file.20\(19\|20\)[^/]*` without `-regextype posix-extended`, also shorter.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a general case answer to your question, but there may be an easy way to do it depending on how much file history you have.  I have often run into a similar situation with months when looking for things in September / October.  One easy workaround is to use the a pattern like this:

```
file.20[12][90]*
```

It's not identical, because in addition to 2019 and 2020, it will also match 2010 and 2029.  Presumably you don't have any files yet dated 2029.  If your archive doesn't go back as far as 2010, than this should be functionally equivalent.